Open3D PointCloud: Setting Material to White Doesn't Change All Point Colors
I'm encountering an issue with Open3D where I'm trying to set the color of a PointCloud object to white, but some points are still appearing black in the rendered visualization. I've tried setting the base color of the material to white, but it doesn't seem to affect all points as expected. Here's the relevant snippet of my code:
# mat_pcp = o3d.visualization.rendering.MaterialRecord()
# mat_pcp.base_color = [1, 1, 1, 1]  # RGBA color

# point_cloud.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(np.broadcast_to(np.array([1, 1, 1]), (pt.shape[0], 3)))
# self._3d.scene.add_geometry("_pt", point_cloud, mat_pcp)

PCP in black and white that is only set to display white

I expect all points in the PointCloud object to be displayed with a uniform white color.

This is incorrect - point_cloud.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(np.broadcast_to(np.array([1, 1, 1]), (pt.shape[0], 3))). You are mixing legacy pointcloud with visualizer that works with tensor pointcloud. Can you share a reproducible code.
